# Image Crop Library for desktop and touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, mobile

I need to find a javascript library for cropping and resizing images that works on both desktop and mobile (touch) devices.  It could be a jQuery plugin although I prefer having something that is more vanilla.

I have searched around and found various options but they all seem to be working for desktop only.

The project I am currently working on needs the libraries to be MIT and/or GPL licensed.

I have found this library named jQuery Image Crop (http://codecanyon.net/item/image-crop/5348464) which does exactly what I need but is not distributed under a MIT/GPL license.

Does anyone have an alternative/suggestion for me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with Jcrop. I'm using it for my project; works fine on mobile. Here is the link: https://jcrop.com/

P.S. [Click here](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) for the old version of the plugin.

Comment: well written lib, but hasn't been updated in years and the documentation seems unfinished.

Answer (score 6):

The library I prefer by far for everything related to cropping is cropper.js

This javascript library has tons of features, is very customizable and has a lot of activity on github:

https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/

Comment: nice, but 37kb is too heavy when you only need cropping and not all the other features.

Answer (score 3):

I've been searching too and found DarkroomJS. It's under MIT license. It does Crop, rotation, History and Save. Vanilla JS and based on FabricJS handling images in HTML5 canvas.

I'm probably going with this to handle user profile pics.

http://mattketmo.github.io/darkroomjs/

Comment: Promising project, so sad it is currently unmaintained.